# tex1Dfetch and Streams in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I have been trying to use streams and 1D texture, but the texture seem to be empty each time i look inside it.  In the beginning my plan was to use 2 streams, but I couldn't access the texture, so I reduced the number of streams to 1 (for debugging), reduced the kernel to 1 block of 1 thread, as you can see below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cuda.h>

texture <int,1,cudaReadModeElementType> tex1;

__global__
void textureTest(int *out){
    int  tid =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float x;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<30*8; i++){
        x = tex1Dfetch(tex1, i);
        printf("%d: %d \n ",i,x);
    }
    out[0]=x;
}

void testTextureCPU(){
    const int N = 100/2;
    int *array_d0;
    int *array_d1;
    int *array_h;
    int x=0;
    int *out_d0 =(int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    int *out_d1 =(int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    int *out_h =(int *)calloc(2, sizeof(int));

    cudaStream_t stream0, stream1;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream0);
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);   

    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&array_d0, (30 * 8*sizeof(int)),cudaHostAllocDefault);
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&array_d1, (30 * 8*sizeof(int)),cudaHostAllocDefault);
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&array_h, (30 * 8*sizeof(int)),cudaHostAllocDefault);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&out_d0,  1 *sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&out_d1,  1 *sizeof(int));
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&out_h, (2*sizeof(int)),cudaHostAllocDefault);


    array_h[8 * 10 + 0] = 10;
    array_h[8 * 11 + 1] = 11;
    array_h[8 * 12 + 2] = 12;
    array_h[8 * 13 + 3] = 13;
    array_h[8 * 14 + 4] = 14;
    array_h[8 * 15 + 5] = 15;
    array_h[8 * 16 + 6] = 16;
    array_h[8 * 17 + 7] = 17;

    for(x=0; x<2; x++){

        cudaMemcpyAsync(array_d0, array_h, (30 * 8*sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream0);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(array_d1, array_h, (30 * 8*sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream1);

        cudaBindTexture(NULL,tex1,array_d0, (30 * 8 *sizeof(int)));

        textureTest<<<1,2,0,stream0>>>(out_d0);

        cudaBindTexture(NULL,tex1,array_d0, (30 * 8 *sizeof(int)));

        textureTest<<<1,2,0,stream1>>>(out_d1);

        cudaMemcpyAsync(out_h+x, out_d0 , 1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream0);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(out_h+x+N, out_d1 ,1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream1);
    }
} 

int main(void){
    testTextureCPU();
    return 0;
}
```

But I can't figure out what's wrong with this code, and how to make it work for one or more streams.

Comment: cudaBinddataure - this function I have not seen earlier..where is the documentation of it

Comment: Could you correct and combine the code you have written into a complete example someone else could run? As it stands, this code won't compile and nobody could run it. When your question is "why doesn't this work", it is important that "this" is actually something someone else could run to try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I edited the code and added a example that can be run.  Yogi, yes it was my mistake.

Comment: Also, for future reference, please read [this meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/163653) on code formatting in questions. What you posted in this question was a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited code contains a number of absolutely elementary errors which have nothing to do with textures or their usage with streams:

1. In the kernel, you have a broken printf statement which treats a floating point value as an integer
2. In the host code, the host memory you use to populate the texture is mostly uninitialised
3. Within the host loop, there is a terrible buffer overflow with the second cudaMemcpyAsync call

If you fix these three things, the code works as expected. I would suggest paying a little more attention to the quality of you code in future.

Comment: That's right, i had not seen the floating point and the integer problem. For the second point, i made it just for the example, in my code each cell is initialised. However for the third point, I do not understand why there is a buffer overflow on the second `cudaMemcpyAsync` ? is it because `array_h` is copied in `array_d0` and `array_d1`?

Comment: out_h has size int[2]. You are copying to out_h + 50 + x, which is undefined. That is a buffer overflow. And please keep in mind that the only answers you can get here are based on the code you post. If the posted code isn't representative of your usage case, how can you possibly expect anyone to know that? I would appreciate it if you would accept this answer just to get the question off the unanswered queue.